# Morphological thickening/dilation while trying to preserve shape in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I'm thickening a binary image. I wished to grow the label n pixels to each direction.

Original image:

[image: Original label image]

At first I used the function bwmorph(I, 'thicken', 25) and got this image :

[image: After morphological thickening]

Which is no good. The thickening seems to use the structuring element [0,1,0;1,1,1;0,1,0], so it always transforms circles into diamonds. imdilate with the mentioned structuring element results in the same output.

Next I tried dilating the original image iteratively for n=25 times with the structuring element[1,1,1; 1,1,1; 1,1,1] and got the following image:

[image: iterative dilation]

The original shape is now completely gone.

I understand that dilation will always distort the border to some degree. I experimented with the structuring element 'disk' (r=5, dilated 5 times) and got fairly good results:

[image]

Is this as good as it gets? Which structuring element should I choose if I wish to preserve the original circular shape as well as possible? Are there any good rules of thumbs for finding the right size for a particular dilation distance (which can vary from 10-100 and the labels vary from circular to elliptical)? Is there a better way of growing a binary image in all the directions while trying to keep the original shape?

Is there a way to keep the Euler characteristic -preserving quality of thicken while changing the structuring element to something more suitable?

Comment: Fit and smooth the contour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
bw = imread('bw.png');
figure; imshow(imdilate(bw, strel('arbitrary', bw)))
```

I am using the image itself for extending it. It gives a more shape-preserving growth:

[image]

UPDATE: As @Tapio said, one can easily adjust the resize factor using `imresize`:

```
 figure; imshow(imdilate(bw, strel('arbitrary', imresize(bw, 0.5))))
```

with the following output:

[image]

Comment: This works extremely well. imdilate(bw, strel('arbitrary', imresize(bw, 0.1)))    keeps the borders intact and lets you adjust the growth size.

Comment: You are right, it is much more convenient to use `imresize`. I will update my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you use only unitary structuring elements, then you will always face the problems you described. If you want to dilate a shape with a structuring element of size N, do not use N times a structuring element of size 1, else you will end up with beautiful unexpected deformation.

If you want to do a dilation of size N, try a disk of radius N. However, it will be much longer to process.

An other solution is to use a distance map: the shape is the seed (distance 0), then everything at a distance smaller than N is your result. It will be pretty similar to the dilation of size N.

Comment: The distance map seems extremely useful! However in this case the original images are ~2000x1000 and mostly 0's, as its convenient to be able to overlay the labels with the orignal rgb images without keeping track of the cordinates separately. So doing distance transforms is actually an order of magnitude slower than large strel dilation, at least on the tests I did.

Comment: The distance map is simply a mean to compute the transformation, it's not a result by itself. Once you compute the distance map, then you find the labels. It should be very quick to compute a distance map on an image 2000x1000.

Comment: Sure, I understood. I just noticed that when running a few tests on my machine in my case the initial distance transform was usually an order of magnitude slower than just dilating with an N -sized disk. Both were so quick that it does not matter, just noted that in this case dilating with a large disk is viable.

Comment: Ok, understood! :-)